# Conjunction redundancy

Tags: exam-questions

> On my request Amar introduced me to his friend who is a singer and a scientist.

My book says since both the nouns belong to same person the **a** before scientist can be eliminated.

> One of my friends is both a novelist and a poet.

Does this rule apply to above sentence also ? Or Since it is mentioned *both* we need to use article with both nouns ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

In "He is a singer and scientist", the structure *He is a {something}* applies to both activities.

Your sentence "My friend is both a novelist and a poet" can be written as "My friend is a novelist and poet" (the word "both" is also optional).

Comment: I agree both is also optional but if I had to use both then do I need to use second a before poet or it can be eliminated ? I.e. One of my friends is both a novelist and  poet. Is this correct ?

Comment: @user212388 "both" does not affect whether you need to use a second "a", so it is also optional.